# Video files organizer for mac

Tags: macos, applications, software-recommendation, video

I'm looking for an app to organize my video files (movies, series, etc.) much like iTunes does with music. I'd like it to have series support (separating seasons and ordering episodes) and to have an option for adding posters/covers to every movie/series.

Is there something like that?

I'd rather if it was a free app, but I'm not limited to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgive me if I've missed something, but iTunes organizes video files and meets all of your stated requirements as of the time of this posting.

You can add images to the file's metadata, set the season, and set the episode by right-clicking on the file, selecting 'get info', and entering the data in the appropriate spaces.

iTunes will display files' artwork and split seasons.  It even has different views available in a menu in the upper-right corner of the window[image: iTunes TV Shows View].

[image: iTunes TV Shows List View]

Comment: I had no idea iTunes could do that! :O

Can I use an external player or I'll have to play my movies on iTunes?

Comment: iTunes will play the videos for you.  As an added bonus, you can also use Home Sharing to link other Apple devices to your iTunes library.  This allows you to play anything in the library on any device, so long as you are on the same network.

Answer (score 0):

**iTunes** has entire sections dedicated to Movies and TV Shows, alongside Music, that allows you to do everything that you asked for. Files can be imported in your iTunes Music library, or a separate library, and can be organised into series/seasons and episodes, with cover photos.